# Plotting a Gravity-Field

Tags: plotting, vector

I try to plot a 2D gravity field or something similar in the form like $r/|r|^3$ with the standart builtin VectorPlot function:

```
VectorPlot[{-x/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2), -y/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2)}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

It should look like: [image: what it should look like]
<sub>(source: [euclideanspace.com](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/space/fields/gravity.png))</sub>

I get something strange when I run my command:

[image: what i get]

Any suggestions?

Thanks Cx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need `VectorPoints` to be adjusted, also, gravity explodes for point mass so it is good to adjust `VectorScale` and cut off the point mass with `RegionFunction`:

```
VectorPlot[-#/Norm[#]^3 &[{x, y}], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
           VectorPoints -> 20, VectorScale -> .3, 
           RegionFunction -> (Norm[{#, #2}] > .1 &), 
           ImageSize -> 500, PlotRange -> 1]
```

[image]

In order to reproduce your plot you need to play with `VectorScale` 3rd element:

```
VectorPlot[-#/Norm[#]^3 &[{x, y}], {x, -1, 2}, {y, -1, 1}, VectorPoints -> 30, 
        VectorScale -> {.1, Automatic, (#5)^(1/3) &}, 
        RegionFunction -> (Norm[{#, #2}] > .1 &), ImageSize -> 500, 
        PlotRange -> {{-1, 2}, {-1, 1}}, VectorStyle -> "Pointer", 
        GridLines -> ({#, #} &[Join[Range[-1, 2, .1], {{0, Directive[Thick, Blue]}}]]), 
        Epilog -> {EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}], Red, Disk[{0, 0}, .05]}, 
        AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if I apply `VectorDensityPlot` to the same function argument I get still strange results (no decay).

Comment: @cxkoda You have to play with `ColorFunction` the reason is the same. This field is exploding in the center and rescaled values are not different enough on the most of the area.

Comment: I wonder why I haven't thought about that. Now everthing is clear, thank you very much.

Comment: Can you explain to me how `RegionFunction -> (Norm[{#, #2}] > .1 &)` works? I know `#` means slot, but what is it in this case? Replacing them with `x` and `y` doesn't work.

Comment: @Cazo `RegionFunction` should be a function that will be used like `regF[ x, y ]` internally, where `x, y` are coordinates of points. You can write `Function[{x,y}, Norm[{x,y}...` or you can use slots instead of named arguments: ` Norm[{#, #2}...&`.