# Plotting radial electric field with `VectorPlot`

Tags: plotting, vector

I've been trying to plot the radial vector field given by a point charge. The basic shape of the field is very easy to obtain, given by:

```
VectorPlot[{x, y}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}].
```

However this does not take into account the fact that the strength of the electric field drops of proportional to $\frac{1}{r^2}$ (where $r$ is the radial distance from the charge), giving vectors which increase in magnitude as you vary further from the charge.

I would like to scale the vectors so that their magnitude drops off as a function of $\frac{1}{r^2}$; I know it will involve `VectorScale`, however am new to how to use it exactly.

Comment: `VectorPlot[{x, y}/(x^2+y^2), {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]`?

Comment: What you're plotting is proportional to the field of a point charge times $r^3$ .  The correct electric field is proportional to `{x,y}/(x^2+y^2)^(3/2)`.

Comment: @yohbs The (unit) direction is `{x,y}/Sqrt[x^2+y^2]`, so you need an extra factor of $1/r$.

Comment: @aidangallagher4 You'll also need to deal with the fact that the field diverges at the origin.  See e.g. [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104080/need-vectorplot-to-ignore-centre-of-region).

Comment: Thanks @jjc385, write a brief answer and I'll mark as answered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Getting the field right

There are two issues involved:

- The magnitude of your vector needs to be (proportional to) $\frac{1}{r^2}$
- You need to multiply the magnitude by the unit direction

The unit direction is `{x,y}/(x^2+y^2)^(1/2)`.

Scaling by the magnitude of `1/(x^2+y^2)`, you obtain

```
electricField = {x,y}/(x^2+y^2)^(1/2)
```

### Getting the plot right

(This issue is essentially a duplicate of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104080/need-vectorplot-to-ignore-centre-of-region).  What follows is borrowed heavily from the answers there.)

Naively you'd write

```
Plot[electricField, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

but since the field diverges at the origin, this is nearly useless.

Instead, you can do

```
VectorPlot[
   If[x^2 + y^2 > 0.2, electricField, 0], 
   {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x^2 + y^2 > 0.2]
]
```

> [image: Fixed vector plot]

- The `RegionFunction` tells `VectorPlot` to ignore points close to the origin
- The `If` statement, while seemingly redundant, makes sure `VectorPlot` doesn't put an extraneous vector at the origin.